# Advice on a HDD/SDCard docking station

Tags: hard-disk, sata

I am looking for a docking station that allows me to easily plugin a IDE or SATA HDD and a SD card. It would be handy if it also allows to "clone/duplicate" between hard disks as I have a few faulty disks with data that might be recoverable that way. However I see so many things online, and so many people saying "this is crap, hard disk doesn't fit" or "it broke after using a few times" etc... I am a little scared on ordering one (I have to order online, don't think I will find this in any local store).. I am also not 100% sure if a clone/duplicator dock can also just straight read the data using USB to my PC?

Basically I need something that:

- Reads IDE/Sata/Sdcards through USB
- Is able to clone between the 2 hard drive slots
- Is decent quality

Preferably a dock that can read those pesky WD IDE drives that seem to be an issue.

Comment: The same here, four years later and I don't know if a dock station is a good idea. Electronics are quite simple, two SATA to USB conversion and then just a USB hub 2 to 1. There is also the alternative option to buy the cases separately and a USB hub, like that if sth gives any problem I would need to replace just that part. I am considering buying [this dock](https://www.amazon.es/Alxum-Estaci%C3%B3n-Acoplamiento-clonaci%C3%B3n-estaci%C3%B3n/dp/B01K7GC1VW/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=Alxum%2Bsata%2Busb%2B3.0&sr=8-5&th=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is all I could find:

https://www.bestfinds.org/dual-ide-sata-drive-docking-station-with-memory-card-reader-usb-2-0-hub-c3a76a3b38acef05.html

https://www.bestfinds.org/camonity-2-5-3-5-sata-ide-hdd-docking-station-clone-hdd-enclosure-usb-2-ports-usb-2-0-hub-ms-m2-xd-cf-sd-tf-card-reader-480mbps-4c4567df2d676c02.html

I hope these help.